# Mittag-Leffler function

Tags: plotting, special-functions

What is the command to plot the Mittag-Leffler function in 3D by using Mathematica program?
 I have tried the command 
`Plot3D[mittagLefflerE[v,t],{t,0,5}]` , unfortunately does not help!

Comment: a) the code you provided isn't in the appropriate syntax for `Plot3D` b) looks as if it's a 1D function? Unless you want the complex plot in which case c) you can find something to do this for you in the docs: ``ContourPlot[Re[MittagLefflerE[2, x + I y]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
Contours -> 24]``

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you need to avoid the $\alpha=0$ line:

```
Plot3D[MittagLefflerE[α, z], {α, 0.1, 2}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I've contacted WR support to point out that for $\alpha=0$ the ML function should give a well-defined limit instead of bugging out.